# I can't figure out why my circles are being placed in a diagonal line

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am currently working on a piece of python turtle code that requires me to randomly place circles within my square. For some reason, they are always placed in a diagonal line and do not get drawn randomly.

```
import random
import turtle

for i in range(15):
    # draws 15 circles and then stops
    random_position = random.randint(-80,90)
    
    # allows the computer to pick any number between -80 and 90 as an x or y co-ordinate
    pit_x = random_position 
    pit_y = random_position 
    pit_radius = 7
      
    # radius of circle
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(pit_x, pit_y-pit_radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(pit_radius)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.hideturtle()
     
    # the circle is now a black hole
```

This is how it appears:

[image: result]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are using the same value for the x and the y coordinate. No wonder the circles are on a diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use

```py
pit_x = random.randint(-80,90)
pit_y = random.randint(-80,90)
```

Or if you want a function (I think you wanted to do random_pos for each one)
Just

```py
def randomPitNumber():
  return random.randint(-80, 90)
```

Then

```py
    pit_x = randomPitNumber()
    pit_y = randomPitNumber()
```

And remove `random_position` Variable.

Tip: To help correct answers that some people answer, press the check mark  beside it, so you mark it for other people as the right answer.

Comment: thank you! it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

`pit_x` and `pit_x` are equal. Do this instead:

```py
pit_x = random.randint(-80,90)
pit_y = random.randint(-80,90)
```

Comment: ah that worked! thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You only pick one random number, then use that for both coordinates. And x=y is a diagonal line.

`random_position` is randomly generated, but it's not itself a generator - just a number.

I would also advise putting the drawing code in its own function, so:

```py
import random
import turtle

def black_hole(pit_x, pit_y, pit_radius):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(pit_x, pit_y-pit_radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(pit_radius)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.hideturtle()

for i in range(15):
    black_hole(random.randint(-80,90), random.randint(-80,90), 7)
```

Comment: ah okay, thank you!